# Force Main view to recreate after preferences

Tags: android, android-view

So I have my main activity that has some views and I have an activity that has the preferences.

I want to, when the activity of the preferences is destroyed, to recreate my main activity, because some views depend on the preferences.

I don't see a way to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what's changed in `onResume()` of your main `Activity`. Then, based on whatever your logic is, set the `contentView` to the appropriate `Views` or manipulate whatever `Views` you need to.

Answer (score 0):

for me I always make all work in separated method and call it in onCreate()..

i.e:

```
   @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
             //here call method contains views initializing, logic, etc..  
            initializingPro();
}

private void initializingPro(){
//....
webview=(WebView)findById(R.id.webb);

//....
}
```

now in you case you want to recreate those components, just call this method again ***initializingPro()*** ,, no need to destroy activity..

good luck,

Comment: I thought of this too, but I'm using fragments, and I need the inflater that is passed in the `onCreateView`. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: You can always get such an inflater by saving it to a class field, or by using `Inflater.from(Context context)`